How to force wifi detection in Fedora
I am using Fedora 39 and I am experiencing the following ennoyant bug.
If I start my laptop without ethernet cable plugged in, it is all good my wifi connection is working fine. But if I was working on my laptop with the ethernet cable plugged in, then the wifi won't work when I remove the cable. I won't even see any wifi information in the settings as if my wifi card is not recognized anymore. Only solution for me is then to reboot my laptop. So, I have 2 questions:

Any idea what is going on and how to fix it permanently?
Any idea of script that could fix the wifi without me rebooting ? (I tried few things in the command line without success) ?

Thank you in advance for your help
